# How to change title bar color in android activity?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set title background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color)

How can I change the titlebar color in an Android app?

I tried:

```
this.setTitleColor(Color.BLUE);
```

but it changes color of written text on it not title bar color.

Comment: Yep, definitely. Vote to close, please.

Answer (score 6):

getWindow() method of Context return the current view context, for get the title bar of an Activity, android.id.id.title

```
View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`
```

Comment: it does n't work for me........gives a run time error

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @vNext were you able to resolve this error ?