# How to programmatically change title bar colour to hex value?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

Is it possible to change the colour of the title text within the action bar to a colour of a hex value? I'm only aware of the following and have no idea if this can be achieved:

```
setTitleColor(Color.Green);
```

Comment: This seems to have been answered already: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386867/how-to-change-title-bar-color-in-android-activity][1]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386867/how-to-change-title-bar-color-in-android-activity
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color

Comment: None of those links show code like the one above but with a hex value

Comment: `this` totally has its place there, I meant to ask what class does it represent?

Comment: The `setTitleColor(...)` method you are calling is part of a class. Can you tell me what is that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Android < 4.0**

You can simply do `setTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));`.

**Android >= 4.0**

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592561.

Comment: I've done exactly that but the text is still white. Btw my app is targeting <= 4.1. `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getActionBar().setTitle("Welcome");

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00")));

        setTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
    }`

Comment: It depends on the SDK you're using to execute it, not the SDK's you're theoretically targeting. Try doing what the answer linked specifies.

Comment: I am using Android Studio - is that what you mean by SDK?

Comment: No, I mean your device's or AVD's Android version. Anyway, if the first solution doesn't work for you, then you're probably running KitKat and you should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592561

Comment: So just to confirm the code you suggested - does go in the 'protected void OnCreate...' part of the java file?

Comment: Yes, that could be anywhere in the context of an `Activity`.

Comment: My project is using SDK version 19 and the emulator is using Android version 19 (4.4.2 KitKat). Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: No, but since KitKat the first solution doesn't work. You have to follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592561

Comment: So are you saying this can't be done programmatically now then?

Comment: No, I'm pointing you to the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592561.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hex color values on your color.xml. Then on your activity you try to add this line of code:

```
setTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.hex_color_id));
```

Comment: So I can't do something like this then?         `setTitleColor(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0099CC")));`

Comment: If it works then you can, but if not you can try another way. Don't just stick into one option there are so many ways.