# how to set custom title bar TextView Value dynamically in android?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

friends,

i have created custom title bar using following titlebar.xml file with code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/myTitle" 
  android:text="This is my new title" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
  android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
   android:paddingTop="3px" 
   />
```

and java code to display custom title bar on each activity.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
```

now i want to set textview value dynamically in each activity can any one guide me how can i achieve this?

using findviewbyid here i dont get reference of that textview to set value because 
main layout does not contains any textbox with such a name but mytitle.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: the tutorial i followed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the way to set the custom title:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if ( customTitleSupported ) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
    }

    final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
    if ( myTitleText != null ) {
        myTitleText.setText("========= NEW TITLE ==========");
        myTitleText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }


}
```

Comment: myTitleText  is null because it is not in main layout dear. it is mytitle layout. when we use  r.id.somthing it looks in layout 
written in  setContentView(R.layout.main); 
in my case it is not in main it is somewhere else. hope you understood my question.

Comment: Test first , speak later. So, where do you think the green title come from ?

Comment: Hi, This is changing the title bar background color but i see some offset left on both side . It is not looking good that way. Can you please help me in solving that problem?

Comment: final FrameLayout titleContainer = FrameLayout)myTitleText.getParent();
titleContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: of course it DOESN'T WORK, when u make custom layout and u look for TextView to setup title in it.. Did u tried dtmilano?  btw if it works why u check if its't null? what happen if it is?

Answer (score 14):

SDK 2.1+

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTitle("========= NEW TITLE ==========");
}
```

Comment: This solution rocks! Somehow the latest features all get hidden under piles of random solutions. Thanks :-)

Comment: does it sets the title at center?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the [`setTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method of your `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

**my_title.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#d4e9a9">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/jetpack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="20px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="New Title" android:background="#a5c639"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="9dip" android:layout_margin="5dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);      
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_title);      

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("gradient shadow");

findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("loce");
    }
});
```

Because custom title default is fixed you should write yourself a theme:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
     TextView mytitletext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
     mytitletext.setText("========= NEW TITLE ==========");
}
```

You can use the `hierarchyviewer` to see if your view is accessible (you will see its id in the hierarchy graph)