# How to align title of Activity on center or anywhere in android?

Tags: android, layout, alignment

```
((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

I have used this above code for aligning my title of activity in `center` but it will gave me a error i.e. "`FrameLayout` cannot be resolved to a type" and if removed the `FrameLayout` then it will give me the same error in `LinearLayout`. I have also change the title bar through `android.xml` file by adding these line:

```
          <application  android:label="@string/app_name">
          <activity android:name=".OptionsmenuAct"
              android:label="@string/app_name"

              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Now I am trying to `align` according to my need and also want to increase size of `title text`.

**How can I do this plz help me............**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll actually want to use a custom title view for this. Check out this question : [how to set custom title bar TextView Value dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416844/how-to-set-custom-title-bar-textview-value-dynamically-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow()
   .getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CEN‌​TER);
```

This worked for me.
But this is an undocumented way of doing it. Google has been known to radically change undocumented data structures, and there's no guarantee that this particular technique will work in the future. So I will recommend u to use it in a try/catch block, like:

```
try {   
((TextView)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow()
   .getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I make a bit clearly variant of **usman** method:

```
((TextView)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.title)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0) does not work on Android 5.1, findViewById(android.R.id.title) works. Also, for the sake of safety, I would recommend checking the result of findViewById for null and wrap (TextView) typecast in try {} catch