# Internationalization in Manifest file

Tags: android

I have some label in the manifest file which has english text how can i have them in other languages also.for e.g.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:label="Main Menu Options" 
        android:configChanges="locale" 
        >
    </activity>
```

I want to covert the lable to persian text.how can i do it.please help.

Comment: wich android version did you use?

Comment: @ZAJ I too faced same prob, once you have all values-fa, values folders, corresponding strings.xml  and locale settings in place, then simply setting support multiple screens true in manifest worked for me.

Comment: i am using gingerbread version

Comment: @ vrs - what do you mean,can you please explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your label value in strings.xml for exemple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- String Resources -->
    <string name="main_menu_activity">جرای برنامه نمی‌توان</string>

</resources>
```

and call in your manifest `android:label="@string/main_menu_activity"`

Edit:
For menu item use it like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item
      android:id="@+id/add"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
      android:title="@string/mu_title_1"/>

   <item
      android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
      android:title="@string/mu_title_2"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: you see i have 2 folders values and values-fa. when i set the locale to fa,the app should go and read from the values-fa folder,but it does not.

Comment: @ZAJ I think farsi language is supported in api 4.1, if you are using a api below 4.1 you will not get it work

Comment: in the output of the code i posted before prints this when i run the app.which indicates it is understanding it is frsi06-28 10:12:27.933: I/System.out(3042): My locale::English
06-28 10:12:27.953: I/System.out(3042): My locale::فارسی

Comment: @ZAJ have you tried another language, like french for exemple?

Comment: can i show the title on the right side,nw it is on the left. something like this---android:layout_gravity="right

Comment: @ZAJ  you can customize the title how you like see those links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438276/change-title-bar-text-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416844/how-to-set-custom-title-bar-textview-value-dynamically-in-android

Comment: @ZAJ same way load your title menu from your resources and set it to your menu item

Comment: can you please give me e.g. i will appreciate it

Comment: @ZAJ and here a tutorial on OptionsMenu

Comment: where is the tutorial??i dont see any link.by the way i am using this to assign farsi text to my widgets. 
  tvCusAddr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cusaddrTV); 
  tvCusAddr.setTypeface(tf); 
  tvCusAddr.setText(Farsi.Convert(tvCusAddr.getText().toString())); 

now when i use setTitle(R.string.mainmenuActivity); how do i assign its farsi text. the problem i have is that if i directly enter the farsi text in the String.xml,the text does not show properly.there is space in between each character

Comment: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/android-optionsmenu-tutorial/ sorry

Comment: i know how to create optionmenu.i have it now whichis working.what i am looking for is to change the text of the option menu from english to farsi.i have two option menu in my activity which i want to change its text to farsi.

Answer (score 0):

Put the label in String.xml in values folder and use the string like app name

android:label="@string/my_label"

Comment: i do that but it is not reading from my values-fa folder's String.xml.any idea why

Comment: Because, you have to set locale to make it read from particular lang file

Comment: 'System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());   
Locale locale = new Locale("fa");  
Locale.setDefault(locale); 
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
config.locale = locale; 
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
Toast.makeText(this, "Locale in Persian !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
System.out.println("My locale::"+Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());'