# android custom title bar in library

Tags: android, title

I created my own library with one activity and use it in another project. But when I create my own app theme with custom title bar for my activities in my project I have an issue. Activity from my library (of course) have default title bar. Any ideas how to solve it with the easiest way?

Comment: Change the library's activity title, that's the easiest way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably extend that Library's Activity and then set it manually. Check a similar situation somebody asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416844/how-to-set-custom-title-bar-textview-value-dynamically-in-android)