# MvvmCross binding in the custom title bar

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to set a custom title bar for an activity, the title bar has a button bound to a command in the activity view model.

Somehow I wasn't surprised it didn't work.

Is it possible to do make it work?

The code:

MainView.cs:

```
[Activity]
public class MainView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       this.RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
       base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
       this.Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.MainWindowTitle);
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
    }
}
```

The MainWindowTitle.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:src="@drawable/magnify"
        local:MvxBind="Click SearchCommand" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
          public IMvxCommand SearchCommand { get; private set; }
          ....
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this feature... but here are some suggestions:

---

If it's just the Window Title, then can you not just bind the activities `Title` like:

```
   this.CreateBinding().For("Title").To<FirstViewModel>(vm => vm.Title).Apply();
```

---

Is there any way to set the window's custom title as a view rather than as an id? If there is, then you could use `this.BindingInflate(id)` to inflate the xml before passing it to the window (no idea if that's possible - but [Android - change custom title view at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time) has some interesting suggestions for internal hacking...)

---

If the above hacking won't work, then you'll have to resort to techniques like [how to set custom title bar TextView Value dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416844/how-to-set-custom-title-bar-textview-value-dynamically-in-android) - using that you could do something like:

```
   // set up your custom window here using non-binding axml with an @+id/myTitle
   Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.MainWindowTitle);

   var myTitleText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myTitle);
   this.CreateBinding(t).To<FirstViewModel>(vm => vm.Title).Apply();
```

I think that would work... although not really sure how it works across the lifetime of multiple activities - guess there may be some playing/experimentation to do.

(This question and answer - [Android - change custom title view at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820398/android-change-custom-title-view-at-run-time) - also suggests other ways to get hold of views/widgets within custom titles)

Comment: Thanks. I am not aware of any way to set it as a view. Meanwhile, I discovered  what you already showed, creating binding by code. I see so many ways to create bindings CreateBindings, CreateBinding, CreateBindingSet.

Comment: Instead of creating binding for each individual control, is it possible to bind a LinearLayout instance to a view model, and have the bindings work on the child controls? In the titlebar layout, I could give the root LinearLayout an id and then call FindViewById in the activity, and try to bind the view model to it. The bindings declared in the XML on each control, I assume will use the view model set to their parent control

Comment: yes - you can do that if you prefer. but only xml inflated by an mvx inflator understands binding

Comment: I can't do code in comments - too hard. Sorry. I didn't say it can't work. I said 'yes' it can work - just make sure you inflate the xml inside bindinginflate. Also I've still no idea about the lifecycle of this window xml compared to the activity or to any fragments.... Sorry - just too hard to do this by comments and feels like this is a a bigger task. I think you can make it work, but not sure what the advantages or challenges are right now - just not a feature I've needed to use. Sorry!

Comment: thank you Stuart. I searched for a way to set title bar by layout in Android but there doesn't seem to be any, all references mention about using SetFeatureInt(resourceId). It's not a big issue anyway, the binding by code works just fine.