# How to change title bar color without theme

Tags: android, titlebar

How I can change background color of titlebar without using theme. tnks in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the following code

```
View titleView = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.titlebar);
    if (titleView != null) {
      ViewParent parent = titleView.getParent();
      if (parent != null && (parent instanceof View)) {
        View parentView = (View)parent;
        parentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      }
    }
```

Comment: @Friz14 Where did you find it? I ran into [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11263829/869501) and I can't find that `android.R.id.titlebar`. Thanks +1.

Comment: I am using title instead of titlebar, and i am not able to change color of titlebar.. do i need to set anything else to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_gray1)));

Comment: if your using android.support.v7.app.ActionBar then use getSupportActionBar() in the place of getActionBar

Answer (score -1):

I think this other dicussion will be helpful to you:

[Set title background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color)

Comment: He specifically asked **without theme**.