# Is it possible to change the color of activity's title bar without FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

All the solutions I have found so far for changing the color of the **activity's** title bar (i.e. the one accessed via [activity.setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28int%29) and [activity.setProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgress%28int%29)) mandate a `FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285722/869501

But I am already using `FEATURE_PROGRESS` and Android forbids combining custom titles with other title features (by way of AndroidRuntimeException) and I don't want to give up that nice progress bar that's an integral part of my activity.

The only hint about a possibility of changing the color of activity's title bar without FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE was in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6582508/869501):

```
View titleView = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.titlebar);
    if (titleView != null) {
      ViewParent parent = titleView.getParent();
      if (parent != null && (parent instanceof View)) {
        View parentView = (View)parent;
        parentView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
      }
    }
```

But if I try to use the code as is, `android.R.id.titlebar` cannot be resolved!

Where do I find that `android.R.id.titlebar`?

Do I have to define it myself? (if the answer is yes, isn't this in essence a FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer (for now, until a better answer comes along): **No**.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if there weren't an "android" tacked on to the beginning of that, I would say that no, it's not a FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, as it's not a *system* title bar.  With the "android" in there, I really don't know.

It looks sorta like something I've done before, which is running with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in the manifest and then creating a titlebar like view at the top of each layout.