# Changing colour for label in android

Tags: android

Can we change the colour of title in an Android application.[image: See the Below Image]

I want to change the colour of label which has contents Abc Supply Company.
This label is in Manifest file. Can we change the colour for this label.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: [Check this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2251787/420015)

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color

Comment: I know for sure you can hide it, then you could just put there your own TextView.

Comment: @sebataz: agree with you and i have given answer with same concept.If i am right then support me

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change color of Application Label that comes in every screen.If i am right then there is no solution

In this case you have use theme for activity in android manifest file like this to remove that label

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Then design you own custom Label in Layout and then you can do whatever you want to do.

Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is known as **Custom Title bar in Android**, check this article: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/custom-title-bar-in-android/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can do.
You need to get reference of your

```
Textview yourTextView = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW );
```

and then call the `function setTextColor( YOUR COLOR );`

Comment: He has asked question about to change color of Titlebar textview.