# Switch color of title bar programmatically?

Tags: android

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285722/599116) to change the color of my title bar. I'm trying to figure out how I would switch that programmatically? Say if a user clicks a button, I want to switch to another predefined color. How might I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with applying color to the title bar programmatically. Changing the layout color programmatically done by,

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.titletextcolor);
```

do this in your button click event dynamically and you will get the color change.

Comment: I mean the background of the title bar not the text.