# Android: Theme changing more than it should

Tags: android, styles, themes, titlebar

I need to change my app title background color. I were able to do that based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color). But this is not only changing my title, but my whole app as well (edittexts, buttons, spinners).
Can I use something like this to change only the title, but keep everything else as the default theme?
I'm using Theme.Black, by the way.

Here follows some code I'm using:
res/values.themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black"> 
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>   
</style> 
</resources>
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black" />
<style name="WindowTitleBackground" parent="android:Theme.Black">     
    <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>                   
</style>
</resources>
```

res/layout/mytitle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTitle"
    android:text="This is my new title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/titletextcolor"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my activity I call:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
}
```

and in AndroidManifest:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/customTheme" >
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: repeated question, here is my answer to it (there are others)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color/9219891#9219891

Comment: Thanks. I tried your answer, changing parent="android:Theme.Black" for parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light", which was the only difference I saw, but this still does not work...

Comment: Little typo above... I changed it to @android:style/Theme.Black.

Comment: I even tried with your entire code, as is, and still no luck...

Comment: The same problem here :/

Comment: Problem solved with @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light!

Comment: yes, that solved it for me too. Although I used Theme.Holo, as I wanted it dark.