# change android label name and color in androidmanifestfile

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi i have to developed one sample app.Here i wish to select the app name is Admin Login and gravity is center and background color is #465371 ,textcolor is #ffffffff.now i have to run the app means the label name only changed here.the gravity and background,textcolor is does not change here.please give me solutions for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidlogin.ws"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidLoginExampleActivity"
        android:label="Admin Login"  android:background="#465371" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:gravity="center">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

i got the o/p like this:

[image]

Comment: All you have to do is customize titlebar and use it in ur app. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all into your custom **`titlebar`**. For the custom titlebar check this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438352/1263679

Comment: i have set the background color successfully.but i wish to need the gravity is center.how can i do.pls help me

Comment: use **android:gravity="center"** into your textview xml code.