# Android: Get rid of gray bar

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image

How do I get rid of the gray background in the image below? I am referring to the background appearing behind the title "MergeLayout". Basically I want to set my own background there, like a header background. Also is there a way to set a footer background? If not can I at least stretch the bridge image to fill the entire screen?

[image]

Comment: post your layout file (xml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color. and which footer are you referring to. Post some code which you have used to achive above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible Solutions

1. To place your own design instead of grey bar you can create your custom title bar. see the example [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)
2. Or you can remove the title bar using the following in manifest

   ```
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
   ```
3. If you wan to show the title over the image you can simply use a FrameLayout where put a textview over Image.

Comment: many thanks. I have not tested the code but it seems correct. How come the download extension is `rar` as opposed to zip so I could add it to eclipse and play with it?

Comment: extraxt using winrar and use

Comment: I will check it out. Don't know if mac will be okay with it.

Answer (score 2):

In the androidmanifest.xml you probably have a style selected.

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Find the style in res/values/

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />

</resources>
```

This will get rid of it throughout the app. No need to rewrite code over and over.

Answer (score 1):

That bar is the title bar.  Add

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in onCreate before setContentView to get rid of it.

You can set a footer by putting something at the bottom of your xml.  Make your main layout a RelativeLayout, make your background image fill_parent in height, and make it layout_above your footer, and make your footer layou_alignParentBottom=true