# change android's top bar background color

Tags: java, android, layout, android-styles

I am trying to change the background of the top bar which is created by eclipse automatically. I have read some tutorials and they suggested me to change "styles.xml" file. here is what I have done so far...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

but this doesnt work. would you please take a look at it and tell me what is wrong with this code? because it doesnt do any effects.

Comment: are you using the old "tilte bar" or the ActionBar?

Comment: I am using old title bar

Comment: did you set this theme for your `Activity` or `<application>` in the `manifest` ?

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color/2251787#2251787

Comment: I set it for <application>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set title background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you reference this theme in your manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Then make sure your style is created correctly, previously you referenced a theme parent that wasn't in your code sample.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>    
</style>
```