# setting background color of options menu panel manually

Tags: android, background-color, android-optionsmenu

I have noticed in the devices of higher versions, the background color of options menu is default set to black. I need to change it to white, as well as the text color to black.

I had googled for it and found many answers, but none of them seemed useful to me yet.

The suggestion I tried is adding this in my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name     .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
try {
LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

// set the background drawable
view     .setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

// set the text color
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
});
return view;
} catch (InflateException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
}
return null;
}
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

But, it didn't help me out.

Comment: i was searching through the stackoverflow, and i think i found a matching answer for your question. Please go through this link once... **[Set title background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color)**