# Change title color in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar that I use, and set title with:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
```

Is there a way to change the color from black to white?

I tried making its own theme and setting it in the xml like this, but no dice:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/statsSpin"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/yourStats"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="@null"

        >
    </ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You mean programatically or via a theme?

Comment: it is repeated question 

answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2285722/2149195

Comment: @RaviKoradiya That answer is outdated, FWIW, for an old version of Android.

Comment: It's not an answer but an info. You don't need to write ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
to change the Toolbar Title. Just write setTitle(getString(R.string.title));
that's it

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Programatically:

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: it will support above api 23

Comment: Not if you're using the AppCompat library.

Comment: worked for me with: `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);` .. thanks!

Comment: can we get a modern answer with darktheme awareness?

Answer (score 29):

Per the [Theme vs Style blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/) by the creator of AppCompat and the post on [version 21 of AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), a DarkActionBar toolbar (i.e., a `Toolbar` with a dark background and light text), can be accomplished by adding `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to your `Toolbar`'s XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/statsSpin"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This will change text color and the default colors to many attributes (such as your `Spinner` to light text as is needed for the dark background.

Comment: Why `app:theme` and not `android:theme` (both work)?

Comment: Prior to [AppCompat 22.1](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), you had to use `app:theme` - if you are using a version later than that (which you should at this point), then yes, you should be using `android:theme` everywhere. I've updated my answer to reflect today's best practices.

Answer (score 28):

Create a new style in application base theme

```
  <style name="custom_toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleTextColor">#replace with color</item>
  </style>
```

and use the style for the toolbar

```
  <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/custom_toolbar</item>
```

Comment: Note that "toolbarStyle" attribute only api 21+

Answer (score 10):

I know there are a lot of answers above hope, it will help someone who doesn't understand above  answers.

Android has view called Toolbar.This view has title which always takes as default color from color.xml resources which item name is **accent**.You can change your toolbar color in two way.

1. Via xml which I recommend you to do that, here below you can see example

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:titleTextColor="@color/White" />Here you can change it.Remember APP attribute not ANDROID
   ```
2. Via programmatically within activity or fragment.

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   toolbar.setTitleTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
   ```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change only title text color than,
Try this one..

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#746E66'>"+titleText+"</font>"));`

it works..!!

Answer (score 3):

You can define custom tool bar style by extending Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar and setting titleTextAppearance and subtitleTextAppearance properties. This way you can change color and text size of title and subtitle of toolbar for reference
http://www.zoftino.com/android-toolbar-tutorial .

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolBarStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyToolBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyTitleTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextAppearance">@style/MySubTitleTextAppearance</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTitleTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff3d00</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MySubTitleTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#1976d2</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I fixed it using the code below and it works on every API level:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomToolBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

```xml
<style name="CustomToolBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/title_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be changed programatically as you can above answer. But reduce code complexity, you should change it via style.xml
First of all create attrs.xml to under **res/values** folder
than add two reference to **attrs.xml** folder like below

**attrs.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <attr name="toolbar_theme" format="reference" />
    <attr name="toolbar_theme_title" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

After defination of reference than create a style in **style.xml** like below

**style.xml**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="colorPrimary">#00A4E4</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#AB0634</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">#AB0634</item>
      <item name="toolbar_theme">@style/CustomTheme.Toolbar</item>
      <item name="toolbar_theme_title">@style/CustomTheme.Toolbar.Title</item>
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
      <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
      <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
     <!-- if you have a navigationdrawer you change it color also -->
     <item name="colorControlNormal">#AB0634</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme.Toolbar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
     <!-- Set title size -->
     <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar</item>
     <!-- Set title color -->
     <item name="android:textColor">#AB0634</item>
</style>
```

Now we have created **toolbar_theme** and **toolbar_theme_title** reference in **attrs.xml** than give these references to our custom theme in **style.xml**

Finally we give this reference to toolbar like below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     android:theme="?attr/toolbar_theme"
     app:titleTextAppearance="?attr/toolbar_theme_title"
     android:elevation="4dp"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Thats it. You can give this theme programatically or set in **androidmanifest.xml** like below.

**programmatically**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme); // (for Custom theme)
    this.setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
 <application
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

or

```
 <activity
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on tachyonflux, to set color with a HEX

```
 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#519c3f"));
```

Answer (score 0):

toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

(toolbar is the name you've give your toolbar in your acitivyt class)
(In your colors values xml set your desired colors and reference it to the color name you chose, as seen here I keep some of my main colors normal names)
Took me a while to figure this out myself but this is the only way I can get it to work, the ThemEditor should allow this but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In xml:

app:titleTextColor="@color/White" as

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tb_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.DarkToolbar"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/White" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme of your action bar using the attribute actionBarTheme as follow. Although it has been added in API level 21 it seems to be compatible with older APIs.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, using Sandip's answer:

```
with(getSupportActionBar()) {
        val titleText: String = title.toString()
        setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#746E66'>" + titleText + "</font>"))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it programmatically by using following code.

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, add this line:

```
local:titleTextColor="@color/the_color_you_want"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the rather simple solution.

It can be done by the following ways (by XML or programmatically).

First (XML solution):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

Second (programmatically):

```
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

The second solution requires min SDK version over 21, for your note.