# How to change the title bar color in android app using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin for developing Android mobile application. And I need to change the tittle bar color of the Android app and while searching internet I have found some of the sample links: [Android Material design implementation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette]) and [Stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color). But I have not found any links to implement this using Delphi. Please help me to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy the `styles.xml` in the ./res folder

Example of a content of this file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme.EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff2b2e38</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0288d1</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item> -->
  </style>

</resources>
```

after edit the androidmanifest and in `<application ..>` tag add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` instead of `android:theme="%theme%"`

Comment: I have tried by changing the black colour to green but only default black colour appears. Is it working for Delphi 10.1 Seattle?

Answer (score 1):

### This will only work with the Include Splash Image option enabled

check this
http://blog.rzaripov.kz/2016/12/android-ios.html (Russian)
https://github.com/rzaripov1990/FMX.StatusBar (demo project)

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_image_def</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**deployment**

```
- Remote Name = styles.xml
- Remote path = \res\values-v21\
```

Comment: In the XML where should we need to mention the color? As you have mentioned remote path as "\res\values-v21\" and should I need to mention the android base version.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the system bars colors (status bar or navigation bar) with my code in github:

https://github.com/viniciusfbb/fmx_tutorials/tree/master/delphi_system_bars

Extra: You can even make it semi transparent with VisibilityOverlapping and have an image behind them. All examples are in repository.

Answer (score -1):

```
SharedActivity.getWindow.addFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Works on  10.3.3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post only in English on Stack Overflow. There is a Spanish site at [es.so]